# CKEditor: Strange tooltip/text beside editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, yii2

I'm using [2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widgetusg=AFQjCNHB1IgnARSUMRqKRvzg55wjc2l64w&bvm=bv.111677986,d.bGQ&cad=rjt), and this is my view:

```
<?php 
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\base\DynamicModel;
use dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor; 
?>

<?php 
$model = new \yii\base\DynamicModel(['cms_content']);
?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'cms_content')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
    'options' => ['rows' => 6],
     'preset' => 'full'
]) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

When I move cursor into textarea, **strange** tooltip are fired beside textarea `"Rich Text Editor, dynamicmodel-cms_content"`.

Am I missing something ?

[image: Tooltip Appear]

Comment: Could you provide the actual appearing tooltip screenshot?

Comment: @arogachev, this is [my screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QwWRR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please write the following code in your CKEDITOR's → `config.js` file

```
config.title = false;
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have jquery conflicts. I had the same issue. I got one of the script file removed which solved the issue for me.